# Problems with Fubinis theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f: (0,1] \times [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ , $ (x,y) \mapsto \begin{cases} 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \  \text{if} \ \ x^2 + y^2 < 1\\
1 \ \text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$

$f$ is a continous and integrable function. I want to calculate its integral over $x$ if $y=0$. $f$ is also positive so Fubinis theorem should be valid. ( or is it?)

With $y=0$ you get $ g:(x,0) \mapsto \begin{cases} 
\frac{1}{x} \  \text{if} \ \ x^2  < 1\\
1 \ \text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$ and $x=1$ is the only case where $f=1$. $\{1\}$ is a null set so it should not change the integral

If I want to calculate the integral if $y=0$ I assumed that I could calculate it with the one dimensional $\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{1}{x}dx}$. But it doesn't converge. This would be a cotradiction to Fubinis theorem.

Now I'm confused and have problems applying $y=0$ for Fubinis theorem. If I want to use Fubinis theorem for this, is

$\int_{(0,1] \times [0,1]}f(x,0) = \int_{[0,1)}\int_{[0,1]}g(x)dydx = \int_{(0,1]}g(x)dx$

this the right way to use it? $g(x)$ is independent from $y$ so $\int_{[0,1]}g(x)dy = g(x)$?

Or is its integral just zero because if $y=0$,  $\int_{[0,1]}g(x)dy$ gets $0$ because the intervall gets zero or $dy$ with $y=0$ gets zero?

Comment: You've demonstrated that $f$ is not integrable, so Fubini's theorem does not apply.

Comment: If this is a problem from a textbook, are you certain you copied it correctly?

Comment: The problem from the textbook states that f is integrable and continous. Therefore Fubinis theorem should apply.  I simply showed that $f$ is not bounded on the null set $\{0\}$ so $f$ might be still integrable and Fubinis theorem is still valid. I am just not sure if you can use Fubinis theorem like this. If one variable is fixed can you just ignore the other one?